# error compiling CPython with very unhelpful message

Tags: macos, compiler-errors, cpython

I'm trying to compile CPython, specifically tag  3.9.0

( `git checkout tags/v3.9.0 -b v3.9.0`)

I'm following the instructions from the book CPython Internals by Real Python.

When I tried to compile with:

```
CPPFLAGS="-I$(brew --prefix zlib)/include" \
 LDFLAGS="-L$(brew --prefix zlib)/lib" \
 ./configure --with-openssl=$(brew --prefix openssl) \
 --with-pydebug --enable-framework
```

I received the error: **configure: error: internal configure error for the platform triplet; please file a bug report**.

Here is a screenshot :

[image]

This is my system:

[image]

Any help will be appreciated it.

Comment: Did you try setting the *env var*: `CXX=gcc` (this is a (lame) workaround)? Or install *G++*.

Comment: No, but I found it is a bug on version 3.9.0 of the python source code. As soon as you go a little further, the issue goes away.